# implode function returning an additional value

Tags: php

so I have:

```
$input=array($fname,$lname);
```

I then use:

```
$valueString = join(",",$values);
    echo $valueString;
```

if I had input `$fname = a and $lname = f`
I then receive:

```
a,fa,f
```

Not sure why I get the 'fa' value and how to edit my code so I get just a,f

apologies for the poor question, though it would be simpler

this is the function;

```
 function insert($coloumn, $values, $table)
{

    $valueString = join(",",$values);
    echo $valueString;
    $insert = "INSERT INTO $table ($coloumn)
        VALUES ($valueString)";
    //$query = $this->dbLocalhost->query($insert)
    //or die("could not insert:".mysql_error());

    if($this->dbLocalhost->query($insert))
    {
    header('Location: blah.php');
    }

}
```

and the this the page for the inputs:

```
   <?php
session_start();
require_once("database.php");
$db = new Database();
$table = "tables";
$coloumn = "firstname, lastname";
if(isset($_POST['Add']))
{

    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];



    $input=array($fname,$lname);

    $db->emptyCheck($coloumn, $input, $table);



}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add new Record</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <div id ="formAlign" align="center">
        <form action="" method ="post">
            <label for="firstname"> First Name:</label>
            <input type ="text" name="firstname">
            <label for="lastname"> Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">

            <input type="submit" name="Add">
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To clarify

```
$db->emptyCheck($coloumn, $input, $table);
```

leads to:

```
$this->insert($coloumn, $values, $table);
```

being called.

Comment: what is `$values`? Are you sure it's `$valueString = join(",",$values);`? or `$valueString = join(",",$input);`

Comment: Your code cannot do so, unless you run it twice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just get two `a,f` because you're outputting it twice. Please show a complete code sample that reproduces this problem.

Comment: amended the question with more code, sorry about that.

Comment: That's still not a complete code sample we could check. `var_dump($values)` right before you join them, `var_dump` any other values you're outputting (not `echo`) so you can actually distinguish between different output. If you still see the same problem, let us know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`implode()` works fine. You are outputting the result of `implode()` twice.

```
'a,f' . 'a,f' = 'a,fa,f'
```

**Note:** I encourage using the root function and not the alias. (e.g. `implode()` vs. `join()`)

Comment: Thanks, i noticed that the function was being called twice and I change join to implode.